# Reduce space between meta-analysis sub-plots in a PDF

Tags: r, pdf, spacing, metafor

I am creating a figure with 3 parts that are forest plots created with the `metafor` package. How can I reduce the white space between the sub-plots so they are closer together?

Here is the example data and code

```
library(metafor)
dat <- read.csv(("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aelhak/data/main/dat2.csv"))

graphics.off()
grDevices::cairo_pdf("plot.pdf", width = 4.5, height = 6)
layout(mat = matrix(c(1, 2, 3), nrow = 3, ncol = 1))

# SUB-PLOT 1
forest(
  x = dat$estimate, 
  ci.lb = dat$conf.low, 
  ci.ub = dat$conf.high,
  slab = dat$age_group, 
  xlab = "mean difference", 
  cex = 1, cex.lab = 0.7, psize = 1, 
  xlim = c(-16.7, 11),
  alim = c(-3, 4.5), 
  #  ylim = c(0, 71), 
  ilab = cbind(
    dat$I2,
    dat$n_studies,
    dat$n_g1,
    dat$n_g2),
  ilab.xpos = c(-10.1, -8.2, -6.1, -3.85),
  header = "Age\nGroup"
)

text(-10.65, 6, "I\xB2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-8.8, 6, "N\nSt.", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-7.05, 6, "N\ng1", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-4.9, 6, "N\ng2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
title("sub-plot 1", adj = 0)

# SUB-PLOT 2
forest(
  x = dat$estimate, 
  ci.lb = dat$conf.low, 
  ci.ub = dat$conf.high,
  slab = dat$age_group, 
  xlab = "mean difference", 
  cex = 1, cex.lab = 0.7, psize = 1, 
  xlim = c(-16.7, 11),
  alim = c(-3, 4.5), 
  #  ylim = c(0, 71), 
  ilab = cbind(
    dat$I2,
    dat$n_studies,
    dat$n_g1,
    dat$n_g2),
  ilab.xpos = c(-10.1, -8.2, -6.1, -3.85),
  header = "Age\nGroup"
)

text(-10.65, 6, "I\xB2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-8.8, 6, "N\nSt.", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-7.05, 6, "N\ng1", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-4.9, 6, "N\ng2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
title("sub-plot 2", adj = 0)

# SUB-PLOT 3
forest(
  x = dat$estimate, 
  ci.lb = dat$conf.low, 
  ci.ub = dat$conf.high,
  slab = dat$age_group, 
  xlab = "mean difference", 
  cex = 1, cex.lab = 0.7, psize = 1, 
  xlim = c(-16.7, 11),
  alim = c(-3, 4.5), 
  #  ylim = c(0, 71), 
  ilab = cbind(
    dat$I2,
    dat$n_studies,
    dat$n_g1,
    dat$n_g2),
  ilab.xpos = c(-10.1, -8.2, -6.1, -3.85),
  header = "Age\nGroup"
)

text(-10.65, 6, "I\xB2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-8.8, 6, "N\nSt.", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-7.05, 6, "N\ng1", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-4.9, 6, "N\ng2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
title("sub-plot 3", adj = 0)

dev.off()
```

[image: otput figure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They can be controlled using `omi` and `mai` parameters of the par function. We set `par(mfrow=c(3,1), omi=c(2,.3,.1,.3), mai=c(.5,0,.2,0))`. omi refers to the outer margins of the whole page, and mai refers to the inner margins in each individual plot. They are always in the order c(lower, left, upper, right); consult `?par` for details. This is the best I could get it to look...

```
library(metafor)
dat <- read.csv(("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aelhak/data/main/dat2.csv"))

graphics.off()
grDevices::cairo_pdf("plot.pdf", width = 4.5, height = 6)
par(mfrow=c(3,1), omi=c(2,.3,.1,.3), mai=c(.5,0,.2,0))

# SUB-PLOT 1
forest(
  x = dat$estimate, 
  ci.lb = dat$conf.low, 
  ci.ub = dat$conf.high,
  slab = dat$age_group, 
  xlab = "mean difference", 
  cex = .7, cex.lab = 0.7, psize = 1, 
  xlim = c(-16.7, 11),
  alim = c(-3, 4.5), 
  #  ylim = c(0, 71), 
  ilab = cbind(
    dat$I2,
    dat$n_studies,
    dat$n_g1,
    dat$n_g2),
  ilab.xpos = c(-10.1, -8.2, -6.1, -3.85),
)

text(-10.65, 6, "I\xB2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-8.8, 6, "N\nSt.", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-7.05, 6, "N\ng1", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-4.9, 6, "N\ng2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-15, 6, "Age", cex=.6)
text(-15, 5.3, "Group", cex=.6)
title("sub-plot 1", adj = 0)

# SUB-PLOT 2
forest(
  x = dat$estimate, 
  ci.lb = dat$conf.low, 
  ci.ub = dat$conf.high,
  slab = dat$age_group, 
  xlab = "mean difference", 
  cex = .7, cex.lab = 0.7, psize = 1, 
  xlim = c(-16.7, 11),
  alim = c(-3, 4.5), 
  #  ylim = c(0, 71), 
  ilab = cbind(
    dat$I2,
    dat$n_studies,
    dat$n_g1,
    dat$n_g2),
  ilab.xpos = c(-10.1, -8.2, -6.1, -3.85),
)

text(-10.65, 6, "I\xB2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-8.8, 6, "N\nSt.", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-7.05, 6, "N\ng1", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-4.9, 6, "N\ng2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-15, 6, "Age", cex=.6)
text(-15, 5.3, "Group", cex=.6)
title("sub-plot 2", adj = 0)

# SUB-PLOT 3
forest(
  x = dat$estimate, 
  ci.lb = dat$conf.low, 
  ci.ub = dat$conf.high,
  slab = dat$age_group, 
  xlab = "mean difference", 
  cex = 1, cex.lab = 0.7, psize = 1, 
  xlim = c(-16.7, 11),
  alim = c(-3, 4.5), 
  #  ylim = c(0, 71), 
  ilab = cbind(
    dat$I2,
    dat$n_studies,
    dat$n_g1,
    dat$n_g2),
  ilab.xpos = c(-10.1, -8.2, -6.1, -3.85),
  header = "Age\nGroup"
)

text(-10.65, 6, "I\xB2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-8.8, 6, "N\nSt.", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-7.05, 6, "N\ng1", font = 2,  pos = 4)
text(-4.9, 6, "N\ng2", font = 2,  pos = 4)
title("sub-plot 3", adj = 0)

dev.off()
```

[image]